# Using a Servlet doPost method

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Im new to Java and trying out some financial analysis java file I'm using for my studies. I got it to work when I created a main method within the bean itself. However when I try to pass the values needed through a jsp form and using a servlet doPost method to do the calculations by instantiating the methods from the bean nothing happens I get a NullPointerException. Im assuming the BlackScholes.java works as a bean should and that the issue is within the code presented. Help here would be greatly appreciated.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException   {

    String action = request.getParameter("action");

    if (action != null) {
        try {
            String spotPrice = request.getParameter("sprice");
            String strikePrice = request.getParameter("strike");
            String interestRate = request.getParameter("rate");
            String timeTo = request.getParameter("time");
            String vol = request.getParameter("volatility");

            double sprice = Double.parseDouble(spotPrice);
            double strike = Double.parseDouble(strikePrice);
            double rate = Double.parseDouble(interestRate);
            double time = Double.parseDouble(timeTo);
            double volatility = Double.parseDouble(vol);
            double carryrate = rate;

            request.setAttribute("sprice", sprice);
            request.setAttribute("strike", strike);
            request.setAttribute("rate", rate);
            request.setAttribute("time", time);
            request.setAttribute("volatility", volatility);

            BlackScholes BS = new BlackScholes(carryrate);
            BS.bscholEprice(sprice, strike, volatility, time, rate);
            double currentpriceC = BS.getCalle();
            request.setAttribute("validation1", currentpriceC);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            return;
        }
    } else {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request,
                response);
    }
  }
}
```

The jsp file used to creat the form data:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/OptionsController"
    method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="docalculate" /> 

    Spot Price: <input type="text" name="sprice" /> <br />
    <p />
    Strike Price: <input type="text" name="strike" /> <br />
    <p />
    Risk Free Rate: <input type="text" name="rate" /> <br />
    <p />
    Months To Expire: <input type="text" name="time" /> <br />
    <p />
    Volatility: <input type="text" name="volatility" /> <br />
    <p />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br />
    <p />
    One call options costs: <input type="text" name="validation1"
        readonly="readonly"
        value="<%if (request.getAttribute("validation1") != null) {
            out.print(request.getAttribute("validation1"));
        }%>">
</form>
```

Comment: use `e.printStackTrace()` in catch block and put the exception details here..

Comment: As @Prabhaker says, show us exception details..

Comment: By catching NullPointerException and returning in the catch block as if nothing happened, you're shooting yourself in the foot: you hide the bug, and have no way to find out where it happens. Don't hide bugs. Fix them. And the first thing to do to fix it is to remove this catch block, let the exception happen, and read the exception stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially one of your action parameters, which you are reading using getParameters is not filled. This could lead to a Null Pointer exception in the subsequent calls where you are parsing.